# Email send options to set a future delivery date?

Tags: email, lotus-notes

Is it possible to set a future delivery date for a Lotus Notes email message?  I would like to compose a message but have it delivered at a future date automatically.

Answer (score 5):

There is the option of using a reminder on your calendar. You can tell a reminder to send and email as an alarm. The subject of the reminder will be the subject of the email concantenated with "Alarm: "+your subject+ the date and time of the reminder.
The text in the Description will be in the body of the email.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any built-in feature within Notes that supports that, but depending on your setup, it might be possible to make an Agent that would force delivery at a later date.

Comment: This is true.  We encountered this request from a client a while back, and direct from the horses mouth (IBM) this functionality is not supported at this time.  But the problem was solved using custom code written by our Notes Developers.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This was posted before the OP's edit to include Lotus Notes. The information will be kept here regardless for any nessecary future reference.

If you are using Outlook 2007 (may work in 2010, unsure about 2003) you can click on "Options" while composing the message and set a "Do Not Deliver Before" Time and date.

You may want to send a test message with this method as e-mail is an unreliable beast.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Calendar → New → Reminder → Notify me → Send notification with subject*.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lotus Notes, provided your connection is up/active, you could disable replication, send the message, and set the replication for the time desired.

The message would then sit in your local mailfile until the replication 'fires off'.

To note: I believe it would carry the time/datestamp of when it was generated instead of delivery date.

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Notes is much more than an email program. It is a sophisticated enterprise solution for large volume corporations. It has thousands of features so it really cannot be compared with a 2 dimensional application such as outlook.

That being said this feature does not exist out of the box - unless you want some sort of hack send-a-reminder-instead solution. There are numerous ways (unlike Outlook):

- Install autohotkey and write the functionality yourself
- Install Firefox / greasemonkey use the webpage and write the functionality yourself
- Study the Lotus Notes API for 10 years and write the functionality yourself
- Get the Dominoes Server to enable SMTP, install a standard email client and use the existing functionality

Answer (score 0):

The functionality does not exist in Lotus Notes as it does within Outlook.  As an anecdote though, an insightful user I knew was able to put something together using [Grease Monkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and the Lotus Notes' API.  Hope this helps & good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using LN 8.5, and there is a function that allows you to send a "timed delivery memo," where LN uses "memo" the same as "message."  Perhaps this feature needs to be enabled by your Domino admin, so it may or may not exist for you.  Try this...
Create > Special > Timed Delivery Memo

This will open a message (memo) with an extra option to specify a date and time for delivery.